# Межпроцессное взаимодействие linux

Tags: c++, linux

Есть две программы на `c++`, одна из которых в цикле постоянно записывает данные в `.bin`, а  другая их постоянно читает. Иногда появляются данные, которые не соответствуют действительности, видимо, из-за одновременного обращения к файлу.

Как я понял, для устранения таких вещей необходимо использовать один из методов межпроцессного взаимодействия. Какой из этих методов Вы можете посоветовать как "самый простой и надежный"?

И, если есть возможность, прошу дать ссылку на пример.

Comment: Учитывая, что вы работаете с файлом было бы логично применять блокировку файла, т.е. `flock()`

Comment: Mike написал правильно. Перед каждым чтением и записью вы 
1) блокируйте файл, 
2) работайте с файлом
3) снимаете блокировку с файла

Таким образом файл выступает средством межпроцессорного взаимодействия

Comment: zeroMQ http://zeromq.org/ например

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin, zmq вместо банального `flock()`?

Comment: Возможно, в качестве межпроцессного взаимодействия можно использовать сокеты, но ИМХО, это будет сложнее, чем делать flock и использовать файл.

Comment: @Mike если одна из программ, в которой используется flock(), начнет работу с файлом, то вторая программа, которая в этот же момент начала обращаться к этому же файлу, встанет в очередь или же выдаст ошибку?

Comment: @AlxZahar https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock  Если флаг LOCK_NB передать - то будет неблокирующая и вернет ошибку, если его нет то остановит процесс до ее получения